# UIImageView doesn't show up in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

Hello I can't figure out why UIImageView doesn't want to show up in UIScrollView. 
Now here is a little catch, I am grabbing picture from library and adding it to the UIScrollView - that doesn't seem to work.

However if I just add picture right at "did load" method then it works just fine:
[code]

```
UIImageView *tmp = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"P3130016.JPG"]];

[scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(800, 800)];
[scrollView addSubview:imageView];
```

I don't know why or where is the issue, please advise!

Comment: debug, and make sure that you are not getting "nill" in tmp

Comment: Does the image file definitely exist/added to project?

Comment: Can you post your UIImagePickerControllerDelegate code where you are setting the UIImageView image value after selecting a a picture from your library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm slightly confused by your implementation, as you havn't posted all of your code, you are initilizing a 'tmp' imageview but i cannot see where it is used.

I'm going to *persume* you need to define the frame of the `UIImageView` after it has been initialized, currently the `UIImageView` has no frame and therefore is not drawn within the view.

You can set the frame like so:

```
UIImageView *tmp = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"P3130016.JPG"]];

tmp.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,width,height);
```

These values need to be float values, where x and y are anchored from the top left of the screen. So `CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)` would draw a 100 by 100 square in the top left of the screen. You can find more information in the documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectMake).

And then add it to the ScrollView:

```
[scrollView addSubview:tmp];
```

---

It is also worth noting that your *tmp UIImageView is currently leaking memory, i would suggest adding it to the autorelease pool on initialization:

```
UIImageView *tmp = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"P3130016.JPG"]] autorelease];
```

Comment: `initWithImage:` method sets the frame to the image size.

Comment: Can width and height be set in Interface Builder?
For example when you drop UIImageView onto UIScrollView?

Comment: ahh, i wasn't aware it set the image frame itself, sorry but my answer is null

Answer (score 0):

If you add an image to the scroll view after the scroll view has been loaded then you need to explicitly tell the view to redraw.

```
[scrollView setNeedsDisplay];
```

An iOS view draws itself as little as possible, so whenever something needing display changes you'll need to explicitly notify the view. See [UIView setNeedsDisplay](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html) for more information.

Comment: Well it crashed, but I quickly found solution: 
[scrollView setNeedsDisplay];

However this didn't work either, image doesn't come up at all :(